# Problem with openconnect after upgrade to ubuntu 18.04

Tags: networking, 18.04, upgrade, openconnect

After upgrading to 18.04 I can't use `openconnect` anymore. Here is the issue:

```
Established DTLS connection (using GnuTLS). Ciphersuite (DTLS1.2)-(PSK)-(AES-256-GCM).  
DTLS connection compression using LZ4.  
Failed to read from SSL socket: The transmitted packet is too large (EMSGSIZE).  
Failed to recv DPD request (1434)
```

I have no idea what it means. Any suggestion?

Answer (score 23):

I have the same problem. Try one of the below:

- run the command with --no-dtls option
- try openconnect version 7.06-2 (not available in ubuntu 18.04)
- try using the cisco anyconnect client binaries instead of openconnect

If anyone has a solution for this problem, I'm also interested to know

Comment: Is this a secure option?

Comment: --no-dtls option disables the UDP tunnel and uses TCP instead. Only downside is a performance hit according to the manual. Not noticeable in my experience.